# Inkscape not exporting to eps parts of a figure

Tags: inkscape, export, eps

So I have an inkscape figure looking in the editor like this:[image]

However when I export it to an eps (or any other format) it shows up like this:

[image]

Where did the big circle vanish to?

Using 300dpi for export, Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939 on Linux.

I have uploaded the svg source here: 
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=18306401242997556392

EDIT: Problem solved. I will leave the question here for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by updating inkscape to 0.91. It was a variation of the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/494115